# Creating Alerts in MOSS Document Library

Tags: document-library, alert

Can any one explain, if I create an alert then to whom the alerts will be send to? I guess the email will be send to users specified in the Send Alert To text box. I have a requirement that when documents are uploaded an alert must be send to a group of users and whenever a document is edited an alert must be send to the document owner/creator.

I also know that it can be done by SPD workflow but i want to confirm the document library alert functionality first.

"Only Send Alert to me when:" will this send email to the currently logged-in user or the user specified in Send Alert To textbox?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll always send the alerts to the users specified in "Send alerts to". The wording in the rest of the dialog is based on that most users don't have that box and will only be able to create alerts for themselves.

To get the "Send alerts to" box you need Manage Alerts permission, which by default is only the Site Owner